# How can I prevent users from manipulating my page via the js console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, console

I tried to manipulate the divs on facebook.com using the javascript console to see if it was possible. I noticed there was a class called "profileLink", so I typed the following into my console:

```
$(".profileLink").hide();
```

But instead of the class being hidden, I got the following error in my console:

```
Error: <![EX[["Tried to get element with id of \"%s\" but it is not present on the page.",".profileLink"]]]>
```

But the method I tried works to manipulate other, lower-budget webpages. How did facebook accomplish this?

Comment: are you sure `$` means what you think it means on facebook.com?

Comment: facebook is not using jQuery, or jQuery does not have *$* assigned. I'm pretty sure facebook uses it's own self-made plugins. Using normal JS will work though.. and no you can't prevent a user from using the console to manipulate elements on your website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Facebook isn't preventing you, but the `$` is not associated with jQuery.

`$` isn't a built in to browsers, but usually is an alias for jQuery.